# LinkedIn share content option like facebook request dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linkedin-api

I am trying to integrate the LinkedIn API into my VS 2012 C# MVC4.5 application.

I used the LinkedIn documentations to call API urls in my application. Currently I am working in the share API for my application. But I don't want to share the contents to all the members in my LinkedIn connections. I see there is option `TextBox` in the `PopupBox` to share the contents to the individual persons.

[image]

Is there is any option to list all the members with the `CheckBox` options like the Facebook request dialog.

[image]

Because some users forgot the member names in their connections.

Comment: Not sure I understood the question correctly. Are you looking to fetch all contacts of the user in-context, using a Linkedin REST APIs? In that case you try using the Connection API, which is like below http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(headline,first-name,last-name)

Comment: Linked in forums will be a better place to talk about their API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, currently there is no way to share to the individual persons using LinkedIn API or widgets. 
Only two options are available for [share API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api#toggleview:id=xml). One of anyone: all members or connections-only: connections only.

Widget has only [url, title, source and summary](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-linkedin) parameters. So even if you get the list of the connections via API and create your own dialog with checkboxes you still can't share via API or via dialog box to individuals.

See LinkedIn related [feature request](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/feature-request-adding-one-more-value-visibility-node-share-api-private)